# Compile error when using if in my environment

Tags: environments, xifthen

I have a custom environment with some parameters. The goal is to basically layout some parameters of the environment. My simplified document is this:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[yyyymmdd,hhmmss]{datetime}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1.25in, left=1.25in, right=1.25in]{geometry}

% External definitions
\newenvironment{testcase}
{
\newcommand{\caseid}[1]{\renewcommand{\givenid}{##1}\label{case:##1}}
\newcommand{\casetitle}[1]{\renewcommand{\giventitle}{##1}}
\newcommand{\caseresult}[1]{\renewcommand{\givencaseresult}{##1}}
\newcommand{\casesteps}[1]{\renewcommand{\givencasesteps}{##1}}
\newcommand{\givenid}{Required!}
\newcommand{\giventitle}{Required!}
\newcommand{\givencaseresult}{Required!}
\newcommand{\givencasesteps}{Required!} 
}
{
\begin{framed}  
\textbf{\givenid \ : \giventitle }
\end{framed}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsubsection}{\givenid \ : \giventitle }
\if\relax\givencasesteps\relax
\else
    \begin{tabular}{p{4cm}p{10cm} }
  \textbf{Steps:} & \ \\
    \end{tabular}

  \begin{enumerate}
        \givencasesteps  
    \end{enumerate}
\fi

\if\relax\givencaseresult\relax
\else
    \begin{tabular}{p{4cm}p{10cm} }
  \textbf{Result:} & \ \\
    \end{tabular}

  \begin{enumerate}
        \givencaseresult  
    \end{enumerate}
\fi

\newpage
}


\sloppy

\begin{document}

\begin{testcase}
\caseid{CaseNumber}
\casetitle{Case Title}
\caseresult{\item Sorry, it failed.}
\casesteps{
    \item This is the first step
    \item This is the second step
}
\end{testcase}
\end{document}
```

This does not compile with an error *! Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored* . It does compile and works as expected if I leave out the second if block, and even if I simply copy the first if block a second time. So this DOES work.

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[yyyymmdd,hhmmss]{datetime}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1.25in, left=1.25in, right=1.25in]{geometry}

% External definitions
\newenvironment{testcase}
{
\newcommand{\caseid}[1]{\renewcommand{\givenid}{##1}\label{case:##1}}
\newcommand{\casetitle}[1]{\renewcommand{\giventitle}{##1}}
\newcommand{\caseresult}[1]{\renewcommand{\givencaseresult}{##1}}
\newcommand{\casesteps}[1]{\renewcommand{\givencasesteps}{##1}}
\newcommand{\givenid}{Required!}
\newcommand{\giventitle}{Required!}
\newcommand{\givencaseresult}{Required!}
\newcommand{\givencasesteps}{Required!} 
}
{
\begin{framed}  
\textbf{\givenid \ : \giventitle }
\end{framed}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsubsection}{\givenid \ : \giventitle }
\if\relax\givencasesteps\relax
\else
    \begin{tabular}{p{4cm}p{10cm} }
  \textbf{Steps:} & \ \\
    \end{tabular}

  \begin{enumerate}
        \givencasesteps  
    \end{enumerate}
\fi

\if\relax\givencasesteps\relax
\else
    \begin{tabular}{p{4cm}p{10cm} }
  \textbf{Steps:} & \ \\
    \end{tabular}

  \begin{enumerate}
        \givencasesteps  
    \end{enumerate}
\fi

\newpage
}


\sloppy

\begin{document}

\begin{testcase}
\caseid{CaseNumber}
\casetitle{Case Title}
\caseresult{\item Sorry, it failed.}
\casesteps{
    \item This is the first step
    \item This is the second step
}
\end{testcase}
\end{document}
```

It's probably very idiotic, but I honestly don't see why my first snippet is wrong and the second is correct.

Thanks for your help,
Y.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do

```
\if\relax\givencasesteps\relax
```

the first time, the macro `\givencasesteps` expands to

```
\item This ...
```

(`...` denotes other tokens that are irrelevant here), but `\if` continues expansion until another unexpandable token remains (there is already `\relax`). Hence `\item` is expanded and its expansion starts with `\@hyper@itemfalse`, which in turn expands to

```
\let\if@hyper@item\iffalse
```

Well, `\let` is unexpandable and it is compared to `\relax`, so the test returns false. However, `\if@hyper@item` and `\iffalse` have entered the scene and the first `\else` is matched to `\if@hyper@item`, leaving a dangling `\iffalse`.

The test should be

```
\if\relax\detokenize\expandafter{\givencasesteps}\relax
```

which will return true when the expansion of `\givencasesteps` is empty.

Beware, though, that only specifying `\casesteps{}` (nothing at all in the argument) will make the test true.

Probably a simpler

```
\ifx\givencasesteps\longempty
```

along with

```
\newcommand\longempty{}
```

in the preamble would do.

Comment: I definitely accept this response since it solves my problem. But I still don't really understand why the second snippet does not have a problem. It's probably because I don't know enough about (la)tex expansion rules. Thanks!

Comment: @YvesV. I'll try and investigate, but my guess is pure luck

Comment: @YvesV. I confirm: pure luck